# Java print input received from collection loop

Tags: java, while-loop

How do I show all input that a user has entered inside this while-loop?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

int times=5;
int i = 1;

while( i <= times){
    System. out. print(" Enter Number : ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    i++;
}

//Show all the input
```

Comment: `System.out.println(number);`

Comment: Using `println()` inside the loop like above is the easy way to do, let us know if you need something different.

Comment: Based upon the comment *//Show all the input* after the loop, you can also add the input to an ArrayList and then display it after the loop

Comment: You are saving all your data in number variable and not saving it anywhere ? This way the data in number is getting over-ridden with each new input !!

Comment: @nathan-wride please be careful when editing

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry about that, my mistake

Comment: Send code please?

Comment: This while loop can be replaced by a for loop: `for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int times=5;
        int i = 1;
        List<Integer> mylist=new ArrayList<>();

        while( i <= times){
            System. out. print(" Enter Number : ");
            mylist.add(input.nextInt());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(mylist.toString());

    }
```

Output ::

```
 Enter Number : 1
 Enter Number : 2
 Enter Number : 3
 Enter Number : 4
 Enter Number : 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```